# Specify SSL Protocol version to use for WSHttpBinding client connection

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, client-certificates

Is it possible to specify the version of SSL Protocol to use when using a web service via WSHttpBinding?

I've been using a trace log to try and determine why my calls to a web service, over SSL using a client certificate have been failing.

The final logging shows an alert `15 03 01 00 02` and the alert code `02 0A` which is an unexpected_error.  I suspect this error is because the server is unable to handle the version of SSL that I'm throwing at it.

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13908] Exiting Socket#15927457::Send()     -> Int32#138
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13908] Socket#15927457::Receive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13908] Data from Socket#15927457::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13908] 00000000 : 15 03 01 00 02                                  : .....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13908] Exiting Socket#15927457::Receive()  -> Int32#5
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13908] Socket#15927457::Receive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13908] Data from Socket#15927457::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13908] 00000005 : 02 0A                                           : ..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13908] Exiting Socket#15927457::Receive()  -> Int32#2
System.Net Information: 0 : [13908] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 79d80e8:7a0e230, targetName = dsl-wholesale-testing.iinet.net.au, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [13908] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=IllegalMessage).
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13908] Socket#15927457::Dispose()
System.Net Error: 0 : [13908] Exception in HttpWebRequest#41613110:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Error: 0 : [13908] Exception in HttpWebRequest#41613110::GetResponse - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
```

I have a PHP based client that does work with the same web service, and I specify SSL version 3 via cURL (`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`).

Answer (score 0):

The version can be set as follows:

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;